# Error in while using function that use in select statement in order by case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have table structure below and i want to use function that i used in select statement in order by using case keyword.But i got the error as saying that FullName is invalid column.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
     FirstName VARCHAR(50) ,
     LastName VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Insert some data to the table STUDENTS

```
INSERT  INTO STUDENTS
VALUES  ( 'kamal', 'sharma' )

INSERT  INTO STUDENTS
VALUES  ( 'john', 'jack' )

INSERT  INTO STUDENTS
VALUES  ( 'Rahul', 'Thomson' )
```

This statement is working

```
SELECT 
       ID
     , FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM STUDENTS
ORDER BY FullName ASC
```

I need this one but it says FullName is invalid column.

```
DECLARE @VAL INT  
SET @VAL = 1

SELECT ID
    ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM STUDENTS
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN @VAL = 1
            THEN FullName
        END ASC
    ,CASE 
        WHEN @VAL = 2
            THEN FullName
        END DESC

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'FullName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'FullName'.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` can not be used inside expressions in the corresponding `ORDER BY`.

Either repeat the underlying definition.

```
SELECT ID
    ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM STUDENTS
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN @VAL = 1
            THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName
        END ASC
    ,CASE 
        WHEN @VAL = 2
            THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName
        END DESC
```

Or define the alias at a different level. e.g. derived table or CTE.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT ID,
                FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
         FROM   STUDENTS)
SELECT *
FROM   T
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN @VAL = 1 THEN FullName
          END ASC,
          CASE
            WHEN @VAL = 2 THEN FullName
          END DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
SELECT ID
    ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM STUDENTS
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN @VAL = 1
            THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName
        END ASC
    ,CASE
        WHEN @VAL = 2
            THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName
        END DESC
```

Comment: You **can** use aliases in an `ORDER BY` but as soon as they are inside any kind of expression they are no longer resolved as aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       ID
     , FullName
FROM (
     SELECT 
            ID
          , FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
     FROM dbo.STUDENTS
) t
ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN @VAL = 1 THEN FullName END
    , CASE WHEN @VAL = 2 THEN FullName END DESC
```

Another variant:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '

SELECT 
       ID
     , FullName
FROM (
     SELECT 
            ID
          , FullName = FirstName + '' '' + LastName
     FROM dbo.STUDENTS
) t
ORDER BY ' + 
     CASE WHEN @VAL = 1 
          THEN 'FullName' 
          ELSE 'FullName DESC' 
     END

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: If using dynamic SQL probably might as well also `ORDER BY FirstName, LastName` so that can take advantage of any covering index on those columns and avoid a sort.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the order-by part around the actual query:

```
SELECT ID, FullName
FROM (
    SELECT  ID, 
            FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, 
            CASE WHEN @VAL = 1 THEN FullName END AS OrderNumber1,
            CASE WHEN @VAL = 2 THEN FullName END AS OrderNumber2
    FROM STUDENTS 
) data
ORDER BY OrderNumber1 ASC, OrderNumber2 DESC
```

Comment: You can't reference an alias in the same `SELECT` list as it is defined in either.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below script:

```
 SELECT ID
            ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
        FROM STUDENTS
        ORDER BY FirstName + ' ' + LastName ASC
```